# Command line variable to GNU make using sh not working

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

Works:

```
make -f Makefile.custom CFLAGS="-DFLAG_ONE -DFLAG_TWO" clean target
```

What does not work is

```
FLAGS="-DFLAG_ONE -DFLAG_TWO"
make -f Makefile.custom CFLAGS=$FLAGS clean target
```

Error:
It starts to think that -D is an argument to make and fails.

Tried:
Using escape characters

```
FLAGS="\"-DFLAG_ONE -DFLAG_TWO\""
```

Any help would be appreciated.

--UPDATE--

This is a workaround but the question still remains open.

```
CFLAGS="-DFLAG_ONE -DFLAG_TWO"
export CFLAGS
make -f Makefile.custom clean target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting is necessary:

```
FLAGS="-DFLAG_ONE -DFLAG_TWO"
make -f Makefile.custom CFLAGS="$FLAGS" clean target
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CFLAGS="-DFLAG_ONE -DFLAG_TWO" make -f Makefile.custom clean target
```

And simple Makefile:

```
all:
        echo ${CFLAGS}
```

...will print:

```
-DFLAG_ONE -DFLAG_TWO
```

...thus it does work.

Comment: it says -DFLAG_TWO not found

Comment: @PravinCG If this does not work for you, most likely you are using `csh` or `tcsh`.  In that case, you must either stop using `csh` (recommended) or use env: `env CFLAGS=... make ...`

Comment: @PravinCG Or you are omitting the double quotes on the value you are attempting to assign to `CFLAGS`